# How to find comment count and review count of a given Article in SQL..?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables :

- **review** (including **content_type_id** , **object_id** )
- **comments** (including **content_type_id** , **object_id** )

---

The combination of "**content_type_id and object_id**" uniquely defines an entity (like article etc)

---

Now i want to write a single **SQL Query** to :

"list all the articles with their 'review_count' and 'comment_count' ".

I mean in final result , what i want is :

**content_type_id**  | **object_id** | **review_count** | **comment_count**

How can i acheive this..??

Comment: Ramandeep. you have made significant edits to your original question, changing it from 3 table to 2 tables, removing the FK constraints and changing the columns in the result set that you are looking for.  I believe my answer below answers your original question correctly and completely.

Comment: Yes, you have completely redefined the question. Not cool. Further, you have many comments below saying you want `article_id` included.

Comment: Yes steven..you answer is correct for previous situation..!!..thanx..!! .. And Those comments were added before i modified the question..and sorry for modifying the question..but i thought my scenario is similar to what i described before, and so i would solve it through answers..Sorry again..But please can u answer it now ..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Edited after question changed *and* I found a data-bug)

Try this one:

```
select 
    content_type_id, object_id,
    sum(review_count) review_count,
    sum(comment_count) comment_count
from
    (
        select 
            content_type_id, object_id, count(*) review_count 
        from jc_reviews 
        group by 1, 2
    ) as r_count
    full outer join 
    ( 
        select content_type_id, object_id, count(*) comment_count 
        from jc_comments 
        group by 1, 2
    ) as c_count
    using (content_type_id, object_id)
group by 1, 2
```

It does not use a central table (formerly called `article`). This means, that items without any comment and without any review will not show up in the result. Items where at least one comment or one review is there will show up.

Comment: it is not working in my case....i have a little bit different scenario similar to this...i have updated my question...sorry for not mentioning the whole scenario...please help..!!

Comment: I also tried your method for populating the result..for my scenario...but its not working....i wrote the following query : "select coalesce(r.content_type_id, c.content_type_id) content_type_id, coalesce(r.object_id, c.object_id) object_id,
    count(r.id) review_count, 
    count(c.id) comment_count
from 
    jc_reviews r 
    full outer join jc_comments c using (content_type_id,object_id)
group by content_type_id,object_id;"

Comment: @RamandeepSingh: It would help, if you a) don't change the course in the middle of the flight and b) if you would state what the problem is. This way I do not have a clue if you get wrong data or if you have a mere syntax problem.

Comment: problem with query that i have added in the comment is : it is giving wrong results..i mean it is multiplying comment_count and review_count and showing the multiplied value in both column in a row..!!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT article_id, article_name,
(
    select count(review_id)
    from review 
    where article_id = a.articles
) review_count,
(
   select count(comments _id)
    from comments 
    where article_id = a.articles
) comment_count
FROM articles a
```

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head but I think it would work:

```
SELECT
article_id,
article_name,
count(review_id) as review_count,
count(comment_id) as comment_count
FROM articles a, reviews b, comments c
WHERE
a.article_id = b.article_id OR
a.article_id = c.article_id
```

This would go only for articles with reviews and/or comments. To get ones without use a left join.

Comment: You'll want to do a `count(distinct)`, as well as throw in a `group by`.

Comment: What i want is : A table that will contain only " article_id | review_count | comment_count " ....and no JOIN with Articles table. Whenever i need to view Articles, i will put a join myself..Now tell me how to acheive that..??

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.article_id,
    coalesce(rc.review_count, 0) as review_count,
    coalesce(cc.comment_count, 0) as comment_count
from articles a
left outer join (
    select article_id, count(*) as review_count
    from review
    group by article_id
) rc on a.article_id = rc.article_id
left outer join (
    select article_id, count(*) as comment_count
    from comments
    group by article_id
) cc on a.article_id = cc.article_id
```

Comment: What i want is : A table that will contain only " article_id | review_count | comment_count " ....and no JOIN with Articles table. Whenever i need to view Articles, i will put a join myself..Now tell me how to acheive that..??

Comment: @RamandeepSingh I joined with Articles table in case an article has no reviews or comments yet. That allows you to show a zero for those counts. Otherwise the article would not show in the results at all. Please specify the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I would begin by keeping a consistent naming convention on my tables and keep them all named in the singular

```
SELECT article_id = a.article_id
       ,review_count = COUNT(DISTINCT(r.review_id))
       ,comment_count = COUNT(DISTINCT(c.comment_id))
  FROM article a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN review r
    ON a.article_id = r.article_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN comment c
    ON a.article_id = c.article_id
 GROUP BY a.article_id
```

Here's some test data to play with:

```
-- Create tables
CREATE TABLE article(article_id INT)
CREATE TABLE review(review_id INT, article_id INT)
CREATE TABLE comment(comment_id INT, article_id INT)

-- Create some test data
INSERT INTO article SELECT 1
INSERT INTO article SELECT 2
INSERT INTO article SELECT 3

INSERT INTO review SELECT 10, 1
INSERT INTO review SELECT 20, 2
INSERT INTO review SELECT 30, 2
INSERT INTO review SELECT 40, 3
INSERT INTO review SELECT 50, 3
INSERT INTO review SELECT 60, 3

INSERT INTO comment SELECT 200, 1
INSERT INTO comment SELECT 300, 1
INSERT INTO comment SELECT 400, 2
INSERT INTO comment SELECT 500, 2
INSERT INTO comment SELECT 600, 3
```

After you significantly changed your question, I believe this query will provide you an answer:

```
SELECT u.content_type_id
       ,u.object_id
       ,review_count = SUM(u.review_count)
       ,comment_count = SUM(u.comment_count)
  FROM
    (
    SELECT content_type_id
           ,object_id
           ,review_count = COUNT(*)
           ,comment_count = 0
      FROM review
     GROUP BY content_type_id, object_id
     UNION
    SELECT content_type_id
           ,object_id
           ,review_count = 0
           ,comment_count = COUNT(*)
      FROM comment
     GROUP BY content_type_id, object_id
    ) u
GROUP BY u.content_type_id, u.object_id
```

And here is some test data to work with:

```
CREATE TABLE review(review_id INT, content_type_id INT, object_id INT)
CREATE TABLE comment(comment_id INT, content_type_id INT, object_id INT)

INSERT INTO review SELECT 11, 10, 100
INSERT INTO review SELECT 12, 10, 100
INSERT INTO review SELECT 13, 20, 100
INSERT INTO review SELECT 13, 10, 200
INSERT INTO review SELECT 13, 30, 100
INSERT INTO comment SELECT 21, 10, 100
INSERT INTO comment SELECT 22, 20, 100
INSERT INTO comment SELECT 23, 20, 100
INSERT INTO comment SELECT 24, 20, 100
INSERT INTO comment SELECT 25, 10, 200
INSERT INTO comment SELECT 26, 10, 200
```

Comment: What i want is : A table that will contain only " article_id | review_count | comment_count " ....and no JOIN with Articles table. Whenever i need to view Articles, i will put a join myself..Now tell me how to acheive that..??

Comment: Where does the syntax `review_count = COUNT(*)` come from? PostgreSQL does not support this, the syntax here is `COUNT(*) review_count`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT  a.Article_ID,
        COUNT(b.Article_ID) as ReviewCount,
        COUNT(c.Article_ID) as CommentCount
FROM Articles a JOIN Review b ON
        a.Article_ID = b.Article_ID
    LEFT JOIN Comments c ON
        a.Article_ID = c.Article_ID
GROUP BY a.Article_ID
```

Comment: What i want is : A table that will contain only " article_id | review_count | comment_count " ....and no JOIN with Articles table. Whenever i need to view Articles, i will put a join myself..Now tell me how to acheive that..??